# Apple Silicon Android Studio emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1, android-sdk-manager, apple-silicon

I just installed `Android Studio 4.2.2` and `Android Studio Preview (Arctic Fox Beta 5)` to my Apple M1 Macbook.

When creating an emulator (`arm64`) I immediately receive the error:

```
AVD Manager: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4a_API_30 has terminated
```

I then went to the log file of Android Studio (Help > Show log in Finder) and I see that the error occurs when Android Studio attempts to run the following:

`~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot-load -avd Pixel_4a_API_30`

which outputs:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.3.5.0 (build_id 7036990) (CL:N/A)
emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable.
```

Tried every possible solution I found online so far...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The latest Android Studio for Apple Chip build fixed my issue.

Comment: Running your app with emulators on Mac M1 ships requires some special configurations (as per Alexandr Sarioglo 's answer):
    1) Add a special emulator from ADV Manager > Add > Pick a model > Next > from Special Image go to 
        Special Images tab and pick any arm64-* value from ABI column (Only emulators with arm64-* works properly on M1 ships)
    2) Show Advanced Settings to increase the device storage (specially for API level 31 and above) to avoid 'not enough space' exception.

Comment: At the time I wrote the issue, I was ALREADY on Artic Fox Beta 5, which means the arm64 wasn't in the special tab anymore but was applied by default. See my comment above.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and found a simple solution after reading the README from the [m1 emulator GitHub page](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview).

If I'm right, what is happening is that you're trying to boot an image built for a different architecture. When selecting the image, you need to switch to the "Other Images" tab and look for an image with arm64-* stated in the ABI column. Everything else should work after.

**Solution Steps**

1. Open the AVD Manager and and click `+ Create Virtual Device`
2. Select a device you want and click `Next`
3. Switch the tab to "Other Images"
   [Android Studio Select Arm64 Virtual Device Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yewcq.png)
4. Finish the creation process and run your app.

Comment: Solutions in similar questions which suggest modifications to PATH variable did not resolve my issue. The above answer from Alexandr resolved my issue on a Mac mini with an Apple M1 processor.

Comment: I did the above. I stated that I am using Arctic Fox beta 5, and using such version Android Studio will offer you the arm64 version by default (no need to go to "other images" tab)

Comment: I see. I haven't tried with the Arctic Fox Beta, but the Android Studio 4.2.2 worked with his approach.