# Android Studio Artic Fox failed to launch emulator in mac M1 with apple chip machine

Tags: macos, android-studio, apple-m1, android-studio-arctic-fox

Android Studio Artic Fox failed to launch emulator in mac M1 with apple chip machine

[image][image]

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306984/apple-silicon-android-studio-emulator-error-cant-find-the-emulator-executable) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67973655/android-studio-arctic-fox-beta-3-on-m1-chip-apple-silicon-emulator-cannot-star)

Comment: Cmd+shift+f (search in Android studio) not works in android