# Android emulator process was terminated

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Error Image

[image]

- This Error occurs wheneve i start my emulator
- I tried installing uninstalling android studio
- I tried installing previous version of android studio
- I tried copy pasting JRE and JDE file in c:/program file/android/android
- I tried installing command process tool (latest) in SDK manager
- I tried installing latest android emulator.

This is what i go in the log file

```
2023-03-05 23:00:31,958 [2307785]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4 XL API 30 - C:\Users\babsc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_4_XL_API_30 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300

2023-03-05 23:00:31,985 [2307812]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4 XL API 30 - Android emulator version 32.1.11.0 (build_id 9536276) (CL:N/A)

2023-03-05 23:00:31,985 [2307812]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4 XL API 30 - Found systemPath C:\Users\babsc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\

2023-03-05 23:00:31,996 [2307823]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4 XL API 30 - Could not launch 'C:\Users\babsc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe': Invalid argument

2023-03-05 23:00:32,000 [2307827]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4 XL API 30 - Process finished with exit code 22

2023-03-05 23:00:32,979 [2308806]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - no accessors for com.intellij.feedback.state.DontShowAgainFeedbackState

2023-03-05 23:00:33,038 [2308865]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\babsc\.android\avd\Pixel_4_XL_API_30.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Pixel_4_XL_API_30

2023-03-05 23:00:33,038 [2308865]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\babsc\.android\avd\Pixel_4_XL_API_30.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pixel_4_XL_API_30

2023-03-05 23:00:33,038 [2308865]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_4_XL_API_30 is online, assuming it's not
```

Comment: does it happen for all(newly created emulator)

Comment: Yes it happens to both existing and newly created emulator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apple Silicon Android Studio emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306984/apple-silicon-android-studio-emulator-error-cant-find-the-emulator-executable)

Comment: @Saad this does not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused because you don't have enough space on your disk.
you can also check the following link:
[Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Comment: Have tried that it did not work

Comment: @kashid if you haven't solved the problem yet  you can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/download/) emulator

Answer (score 0):

I just faced exactly same problem and this is how I solved.
(Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1)

1. Open Device Manager
2. Click three dots (additional menu)
3. Click "Show On Disk"

[image]

4. Delete "multiinstance.lock"

[image]

**Note! If it is in used by "qemu-system-x84_64.exe" in background, then it won't be deleted.**

So I opened task manager and force stopped above software and it allowed me to delete "multiinstance.lock" file.

[image]

Alternative, you can duplicate AVD then delete the original.

1. Open Device Manager
2. Click three dots (additional menu)
3. Click "Duplicate"
4. Delete Original Device.

Comment: No multiinstant.lock in the folder

Comment: @kaskid, try to find any file extension with ".lock" within the folder. Maybe mine was named as "multiinstant.lock" because I tried all my virtual devices and all got locked due to an unknown error. Else, you and I have different problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Media Feature Pack on Windows.
For more details about this issue read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76435812/16400321)

To install Media Feature Pack: Go through Settings -> Apps -> Apps & features tab -> Optional features -> Add a feature -> Media Feature Pack.
After that restart the computer.

Works for me on Windows 10 and Android Studio Giraffe.